# Gradle Issue with TestNG : No tests found for given includes

Tags: gradle, testng

I am having difficulties with testNG + Gradle. My tests have worked fine, but I made some changes to the file where I have tests, and now this issue pops up.

"Execution failed for task ':....'.

> No tests found for given includes : [.....]

I have this in place, but it doesn't help.

```
test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

What does error mean exactly, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when running TestNG tests from within IntelliJ.  I've found that many posts recommend changing the "Run test using" setting from "Gradle" to "IntelliJ IDEA" (Settings/Build,Execution, Deployment/Build Tools/Gradle), but this didn't work for me.

I discovered that on the same settings screen my "Gradle JVM" was set to using a newer JVM: "JVM 11" when our code is only compatible with "JVM 1.8".  Changing this setting fixed the above error.

Comment: Thanks, switching to running test cases IntelliJ did not solve the problem, but it did help solve the problem. I found that this gradle message that i got is quite misleading; it arises each time there is a compilation error in a test case. Switching to IntelliJ actually shows what the compilation error is instead of giving a broad "test cases not found". I am assuming Gradle can't find these test cases because the code fails when trying to compile the test cases, and returns no test cases to Gradle as a result.

Answer (score 0):

in My Case in kotlin I have in build.gradle

```
tasks.test {
useJUnitPlatform()
```

}

so you have to change it :

this works for me

```
tasks.test {
useTestNG()
```

}